# String arrays being truncated unexpectedly (Python 3.5)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to join a list of strings together into a single array element, but I am getting a weird truncation error. This works:

```
>>> x = ' '.join(np.array(['water','road','agriculture','habitation']))
>>> print(x)
'water road agriculture habitation'
```

I need to do this for an array of 60000+ objects, but as soon as I add a for loop the ends of long strings get cut off. Here is a simplified version:

```
>>> y = np.zeros([3,2]).astype(str)
>>> y[:,0] = ['image_1','image_2','image_3']
>>> for i in range(3):
...    z = np.array(['water','road','agriculture','habitation'])
...    y[i,1] = ' '.join(z)
>>> print(y)
[['image_1' 'water road agriculture habitatio']
 ['image_2' 'water road agriculture habitatio']
 ['image_3' 'water road agriculture habitatio']]
```

I am at a loss for what is causing this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str` is not a NumPy type, and doesn't really fit into NumPy's type system because it is of arbitrary length.  I can't find where this is actually documented, but what you get when you request this type is actually `'S32'` - each element gets exactly 32 characters of space allocated to it, anything beyond that is lost.

You could explicitly use a longer string type, `'S40'` perhaps, to hold the longest string you need - but this will waste lots of memory if the average string length is much less than the maximum.  You might be better off using a type of `object` (or `'O'`), so that the arrays hold references to ordinary Python objects - your strings will behave as normal.

Comment: Thanks! Both solutions worked, but went with the object type solution.